# Unable to find matches using Boost RegEx

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, boost, boost-regex

I am using *boost 1.67.0 regex* to find matching filenames in current folder using following snippet

```
boost::filesystem::path p(".");
if(is_directory(p)) {

    for(auto& entry : boost::make_iterator_range(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(p), {})){
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << entry;
        std::string filename = ss.str();
        std::cout << filename << std::endl;
        boost::regex pattern("some_\\d+_file\.txt");

        if(boost::regex_match(filename, pattern)){
            std::cout << "matched" << filename << std::endl;
        }            
    }   
}
```

Contents of current directory, produced by `std::cout << filename << std::endl;` line, are:

```
"./myApp.out"
"./some_0_file.txt"
"./some_1_file.txt"
"./other_file.txt"
"./some_other_file.txt"
"./some_2_file.txt"
```

To confirm that my matching expression is correct I consulted [Perl Regular Expression Syntax](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html). Also confirmed it using [RegEx101.com](https://regex101.com), output correctly shows 3 matches as follows:

```
some_0_file.txt
some_1_file.txt
some_2.file.txt
```

**Question**

Is there anything wrong with my snippet or RegEx? Why `boost::regex_match` produce 0 match?

What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
boost::filesystem::path p(".");
if (is_directory(p)) {

    for (auto& entry : boost::make_iterator_range(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(p), {})) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << entry.path().string(); //2
        std::string filename = ss.str();
        std::cout << filename << std::endl;
        boost::regex pattern(".*some_\\d+_file\\.txt"); //1
        if (boost::regex_match(filename, pattern)) {
            std::cout << "matched" << filename << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

1.`regex_match` only consider a full match

2.`operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>& os, const path& p)` will use `boost::io::quoted()` and add quotes to handle spaces in paths

Comment: This solved my issue, thank you. The only difference with @Ptaq66's answer is `ss << entry.path().string();` line.

Comment: There's zero reason to bother with the stream in the first place. Also, take the regex out of the loop. Lastly, no need for the iterator range (yes, that's [surprising](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator/begin)) Much simplified demo:  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca553af0515f16f3

Answer (score 2):

Because `regex_match` considers only a FULL match. That means, you need to include `./` in your pattern. Also you escaped the last dot incorrectly. Your pattern should be:

```
boost::regex pattern("\\./some_\\d+_file\\.txt");
```

(or you can use `.*` as the beginning of the filepath, just not to hardcode `./`)

Alternatively, you can use `regex_search` which returns TRUE if part of the string matches the expression.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried both `"\\./some_\\d+_file\\.txt"` and `"\\.*some_\\d+_file\\.txt"` as my pattern. Unfortunately none of them worked. Still get 0 match. I am gonna try `regex_search`.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned by @user338371 you also have enclosing quotes in your filenames which must be taken into consideration when looking for a full match.